# Error with old version of Web3 when trying to log Remix contract

Tags: javascript, web3js, remix

I'm trying to get the details logged on the browser console from a simple Remix contract.
However, when I try the following html, I get an error saying:

> web3.eth.contract is not a function

Looking through the documentation, I see that changing:

```
var RemixContract = web3.eth.contract([
```

for this:

```
var RemixContract = new web3.eth.Contract([
```

Allows at least for the assignation of the contract variable, but then I cannot call the smartcontract data using the `RemixContract.at` function.
I believe this is a conflict with the old Web3 version but I can't figure out how to bring the data into the browser console.

The desired output is: Be able to see my contract's details on the browser console.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Deploy a Remix Contract</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
    <!--The following line contains the source of web3 in case it is not on the directory-->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/ethereum/web3.js/dist/web3.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <h1>Deploy a Remix Contract</h1>
    </div>

    <script>

        // Connect to the web3 provider
        if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
            web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
        } else {
            web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:7545"));
        }

        // Set a default account
        web3.eth.defaultAccount = web3.eth.accounts[0];

        // Get the contract abi
        // To get the contract ABI from Remix, go to the Compile tab and grab the ABI
        var RemixContract = web3.eth.contract([
    {
        "constant": false,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "name": "x",
                "type": "string"
            }
        ],
        "name": "setMessage",
        "outputs": [],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "getMessage",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "name": "",
                "type": "string"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    }
]);

        // Get the contract address
        var myMessage = RemixContract.at('0xd9145CCE52D386f254917e481eB44e9943F39138')

        console.log(myMessage);

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 13):

Found the answer, I was using an old syntax for web3, I should have replaced this:

```
// Get the contract address
var RemixContract = web3.eth.contract(CONTRACT-ABI-HERE);
// Get the contract abi
var myMessage = RemixContract.at('CONTRACT ADDRESS HERE');
console.log(myMessage);
```

with this:

```
var RemixContract = new web3.eth.Contract(CONTRACT-ABI, CONTRACT ADDRESS);
console.log(RemixContract)
```

Answer (score 0):

Following your path, next you will have hard times trying to call the setMessage() function with your newly created contract.
If we are on the same page, please try the following code, it saved me ton of time:

```
web3.eth.getAccounts().then(function(accounts){            
    web3.eth.defaultAccount = accounts[0]                        
    var myContract = new web3.eth.Contract(contractABI, contractAddress);            
    myContract.methods.setMessage('your-new-message').send({from: accounts[0]});
    myContract.methods.getMessage().call().then(console.log);
});
```